# "Invalid argument" on the use of fcntl in C

Tags: c, unix, systems-programming, fcntl

I have been trying to understand the reason and cannot find a valid reason for `Invalid Argument` error given on the use of `perror`. Can anyone suggest the reason for this error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{ 

    int fd;
    char buffer[255];
    struct flock fvar;

    if(argc==1)
    {
        printf("usage:./a.out filename\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if((fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR))==-1)
    {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    fvar.l_type=F_WRLCK;
    fvar.l_whence=SEEK_END;
    fvar.l_start=SEEK_END-100;
    fvar.l_len=100;

    printf("press enter to set lock\n");
    getchar();
    printf("trying to get lock..\n");

  **if((fcntl(fd,F_SETLK,&fvar))==-1)
    {
         perror("fcntl") ;
         fcntl(fd,F_GETLK,&fvar);**
         printf("\nFile already locked by process (pid): \t%d\n",fvar.l_pid);
         return -1;
    }

    printf("locked\n");

    if((lseek(fd,SEEK_END-50,SEEK_END))==-1)
    {
        perror("lseek");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((read(fd,buffer,100))==-1)
    {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("data read from file..\n");
    puts(buffer);
    printf("press enter to release lock\n");

    getchar();

    fvar.l_type = F_UNLCK;
    fvar.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    fvar.l_start = 0;
    fvar.l_len = 0;

    if((fcntl(fd,F_UNLCK,&fvar))==-1)
    {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Unlocked\n");
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried checking the arguments. The file descriptor looks good and the arguments of flock are double , triple, quadruple ... times checked. I just can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: How long (in bytes) is the file you're running it on?

Comment: oh wait, does that matter?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting:

```
fvar.l_type=F_WRLCK;
fvar.l_whence=SEEK_END;
fvar.l_start=SEEK_END-100;
fvar.l_len=100;
```

The man page for fcntl (on Linux, at least) says:

> `l_start`  is  the starting offset for the lock, and is interpreted
>   relative to either: the start of the file (if `l_whence`  is 
>   SEEK_SET);  the    current  file  offset (if `l_whence` is `SEEK_CUR`); or
>   the end of the file    (if `l_whence` is `SEEK_END`).  In the final two
>   cases, `l_start`  can  be  a    negative  number  provided  the offset
>   does not lie before the start of    the file.

You are setting `l_start` to `SEEK_END-100`. Since `SEEK_END` is equal to 2 (again, on Linux, though other systems are likely to be similar), that means you're setting `l_start` to -98. If the file length is less than 98 bytes, that will be before the start of the file - which, as the man page says, is not allowed. This is likely to be the source of the `EINVAL`.

Instead you should:

1. Make sure you're using offsets that are within the file
2. Not use `SEEK_END-100` (or `SEEK_END-50`) for `fcntl` or `lseek` - that's not how they work - just use `-100` or `-50` instead.

Comment: So, your point is not to use SEEK_END-100(or 50) and instead use -100 or -50 for the offset set to SEEK_END or simply change the offset to SEEK_SET? Also, why can't I use 'SEEK_END - 50' for lseek? Your input was helpful.

Comment: Yes, use `-100` or `-50` (or switch to `SEEK_SET`). You can't use `SEEK_END-50` for `lseek()` because again, that's not how `SEEK_END` works - you need to use `SEEK_END` for the `whence` parameter, but just `-50` for the `offset`. Glad you found the answer helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If `fvar.l_whence` is set to `SEEK_END`, `fvar.l_start` is an offset from the end of the file.  If you want the lock to start 100 bytes before the end then `l_start` should be `-100` (not `SEEK_END-100`).

Comment: This is true, but since `SEEK_END` is typically a small positive integer (on Linux it's 2), that means the code is using -98 as the offset, which will work if the file is 98 bytes or more long (though it might not lock what the OP was expecting). If the file is shorter than that, changing to -100 is less wrong, but won't remove the error...